# Advanced looping in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

```
create table Numbers(id int, Number float);
insert into Numbers(id, Number) 
    values  (1, 3.00), 
            (2, 3.30), 
            (3, 4.50), 
            (4, 2.25), 
            (5, 6.50);

select min(Number) from Numbers into @minNumber;
select id, Number, (Number - @minNumber) from Numbers;
```

I need to display the list of numbers and next to each number, I have to display the difference between the number itself and the minimum number above the current row (all preceding rows excluding the current row). So the output should be.

```
3.00  3.00
3.30  0.30
4.50  1.50
2.25  -0.75
6.50  4.25
```

Right now, it's only displaying the difference between the number and the minimum of all the number (2.25). Not sure how to run a loop so that it works.

Comment: Is there a primary key in your table structure ? Without primary key, data is an unordered dataset and minimum number will be indeterministic

Comment: Careful! There's no such thing as "above" or "below" in SQL. You need to add a column showing the order. Without `ORDER BY` the server is free to put rows in a different order every time you run the query.

Comment: How do you generate row 4 (the one containing 2.25) ?  Please [edit] your question. And, when you say "above" do you mean "all preceding rows including the current row" or "all preceding rows excluding the current row" ? **Pro tip**: good problem statements lead to good code.

Comment: Your expected output does not correspond to your problem statement: "I have to display the difference between the number itself and the minimum number above the current row"
For eg: check the row for number 2.25 in your expected output. I think the different should be `-0.75` for the fourth row

Comment: Since negative number would be considered meaningless (let's say for volume of a shape), I thought displaying the number itself would be better. But yes, you can also output -0.75 if you wish.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? As of MySQL 8 I'd use a window function (`MIN OVER`) for this.

Comment: Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a Primary key column `id`. **Always** remember that data is stored in unordered fashion, so without a PK, we really can't define "rows above" the current row.

You can utilize [Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) to determine the minimum `Number` out of the rows above the current row (`t2.id < t1.id`)

For first row, there will no be any number "above" it, so we will have to use `Coalesce()` function to consider `null` value as 0:

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j8Rx1eQMiEpWJtZvb2dcGy/0)

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.Number, 
  (t1.Number - COALESCE((SELECT MIN(t2.Number)
                         FROM Numbers AS t2 
                         WHERE t2.id < t1.id),0)) AS difference 
FROM Numbers AS t1 
ORDER BY t1.id
```

---

In MySQL **8.0.2** onwards, we can utilize [Window Functions with Frame](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) as well. We can consider a "increasing" frame from the very start (`UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`) to one row before the current row (`1 PRECEDING`), and determine the minimum value.

Try the following (for **MySQL 8.0.2+ only**):

### [DB Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aEKgupU9ahMoV78Fhdp53M/0)

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  Number, 
  (Number - 
   COALESCE(MIN(Number) OVER(ORDER BY id 
                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                              AND 1 PRECEDING)
            ,0)) AS difference 
FROM Numbers 
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: @SalmanA "I have to display the difference between the number itself and the minimum number above the current row"

Comment: Is there a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient method would use variables:

```
select n.*,
       (number -
        (case when (@min2 := @min) = NULL then 0  -- never happens
              when @min := least(coalesce(@min, n.number), n.number) = NULL then 0  -- never happens
              else coalesce(@min2, 0)
         end)
       ) as diff
from numbers n cross join
     (select @min := NULL) params
order by n.id;
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rq9Dyt1gsimCMdfpBN6WtA/1)

Comment: Hope you dont mind, added a DB fiddle link to your answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with cross join ?

```
SELECT n.id, n.Number, n.Number - MIN(n2.Number)
FROM Numbers n
CROSS JOIN Numbers n2
WHERE 
    n2.id < n.id
GROUP BY  n.id, n.Number;
```

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gUG1TD25cT1dD1mtJqUYBx/0)

Comment: You are producing a huge intermediate result in order to aggregate. I wouldn't recommend this. And this is not a `CROSS JOIN` but only an obfuscated `INNER JOIN`. You should write `FROM Numbers n INNER JOIN Numbers n2 ON n2.id < n.id` instead.